# How to retrieve foreign key object from inside a django model validator

Tags: django, validation

I have two models:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    # photo attributes and methods

class Category(models.Model):
    banner = models.ForeignKey(Photo, validators=[validate_image_size])
```

My validator takes the Photo.id ForeignKey, gets the Photo object:

```
def validate_image_size(photo_id):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    # open the image using urllib
    # if image size too large, raise ValidationError()
```

Is there a way to pass the Photo object to the validator? Instead of the `photo_id`.